# Mathematical definition of "being a function of position"

Tags: functions, physics

A definition of function could be the following:

> A function is a tuple $(f, C, D)$, where $f\subseteq C\times D$ satisfying:
>
> - $\forall x\in C : \exists y \in D : (x, y) \in f.$
> - $\forall (a,b), (c,d)\in f : a= c \rightarrow b = d$.
>
> Notation: If $(x,y)\in f$, given that such $y$ is unique, we write $y=f(x)$.

---

In physics it's useful to have the notion of so-called "functions of position": The force of gravity exerted by the Earth is a good example, say, if you're in one dimension (taking masses and constants to be $1$), this force could be:

\begin{align}
F:\ &\Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R\\
&k\mapsto \frac 1 {k^2}
\end{align}

One usually then writes the equation of motion for a particle $(m = 1, x: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R)$

$$F= \ddot x\tag{1}$$

Notice how, in the definition of force, which is an absolutely correct definition for a function, nowhere it is required that the input is a so called 'position' argument. So if this additional, informal information wasn't given, one could not go from $(1)$ to

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x(t)^2}=\ddot x(t)
\end{align}

To actually have a differential equation to solve.

See the problem here?

---

Perhaps I'm just missing something obvious, but saying something like "gravity is not a function of time" doesn't make sense from the definition of a function: it doesn't matter what you call your variable.

I guess the question is, how do we mathematically represent these physical scenarios in an accurate, not handwavy way?

Comment: What you could say is that en experiment has parameters $(m,t,p,..)$ and that if we have two experiments of the form $(m_1, t_1, p,...)$ and $(m_2, t_2, p,...)$ then gravity is the same in both experiments. This would represent the notion of "depends ony on position"

Comment: When writing the equation of motion, what you actually mean is $\ddot x = F \circ x$, where $x$ is the function that you seek. So even if $F$ doesn't “know” what kind of quantity it is a function of, *you* are feeding it with $x$.